# Does Spring Boot supports Master Slave config of RDBMS DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I have a multiple Spring Boot based Micro services which connect a DB2 data base (Master BD). We want to have same replica of Master DB which is called Slave DB2 DB. Every month we have some maintenance on master DB for 5-10 hrs during this time we want all our apps to automatically connect to Slave DB after this time period apps should switch back to Master without manual intervention.

Is this possible to achieve in Sprint Boot. I thought of using Spring Cloud Hystrix but is it correct architectural pattern. Any other better approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this on the infrastructure level, your apps does not need to know that there was a failover.
If you want to solve this on the application side, you can use [Spring Cloud Circuitbreaker](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker) (Hystrix is deprecated, but you can use it with Resilience4J).

Comment: How does this can be achieved in infra level? you mean do we can control this switch over at DB side or infra structure in which application is deployed?

Comment: I guess this is out of the scope of the original question and also DB-related. There are multiple ways to do this but I think in general the best is when your DB cluster does it, just use your favorite search engine and search for cluster failover and your DB, e.g.: mariaDB cluster failover.